# Show properties about mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$, $V:=\mathbb{R}^n$, $M:=(V^V, \circ)$ and $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V):=\{\phi :V\rightarrow V\mid \phi \text{ is linear }\}$.

Show the following:

1. $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ is closed under $\circ$.
2. If $f,g\in V^V$ such that $f\circ g=\text{id}_V$, then $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective.
3. If $\phi, \psi \in \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ such that $\phi \circ \psi =\text{id}_V$, then $\phi$ and $\psi$ are invertible and it holds that $\phi^{-1}=\psi$.
4. Let $a,b\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ab=u_n$. Then $a$ and $b$ are invertible and it holds that $a^{-1}=b$. Hint: Consider $\phi_a$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

As for 1:

Let $\phi, \psi \in \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$. Then since $\phi :V\rightarrow V$ and $\psi :V\rightarrow V$ it follows that $\phi\circ \psi :V\rightarrow V$. Since $\phi$ is linear we have that $\phi (ax+y)=a\phi (x)+\phi (y )$ for $x,y\in V$. Equivalently, since $\psi$ is linear we have that $\psi (b\tilde{x}+\tilde{y})=b\psi (\tilde{x})+\psi (\tilde{y})$ for $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}\in V$. We have that for $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}\in V$ that $$\phi \circ \psi (b\tilde{x}+\tilde{y})=\phi (\psi (b\tilde{x}+\tilde{y}))=\phi (b\psi (\tilde{x})+\psi (\tilde{y}))=b\phi (\psi (\tilde{x}))+\phi (\psi (\tilde{y}))=b\phi \circ \psi (\tilde{x})+\phi \circ \psi (\tilde{y})$$ Therefore $\phi\circ \psi $ is linear and so $\phi\circ \psi\in \text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ which means that $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ is closed under $\circ$.

Is everything correct?

$$$$

As for 2:

Let $g(a)=g(b)$. Then we have that $$f(g(a))=f(g(b)) \Rightarrow (f\circ g)(a)=(f\circ g)(b) \Rightarrow \text{id}_V(a)=\text{id}_V(b) \Rightarrow a=b$$ This means that $g$ is injective.

Let $y\in V$. Let $x=g(y )$ (we can set this like that, or not? ). Then we get $f(x)=f(g(y )) \Rightarrow f(x)=(f\circ g)(y ) \Rightarrow f(x)=\text{id}_V(y ) \Rightarrow f(x)=y$. So for every $y \in V$ , there exists a $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, which means that $f$ is surjective.

Is everything correct?

$$$$

As for 3:

Can we use here statement 2 ?

$$$$

As for 4:

What exactly is $\phi_a$ ?

Comment: #1 and #2 are entirely correct as near as I can tell.

Comment: Great!! Do you have an idea for 3 and 4? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: I think $\phi_a$ is the endomorphism associated with $a \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ as $End_{\mathbb{R}}(V) \cong  M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: $\phi_a$ might be the left multiplication by $a$, i.e., $\phi_a(b)=ab$.

Comment: For statement 4 do we have to use statement 3? @saltandpepper

Comment: For statement 4 do we have to use statement 3? @ThomasShelby

Comment: I believe so , given $\phi_a$ is what I said. @MaryStar

Comment: $u_n$ is the identity element, right? If yes, note that $\phi_a\circ\phi_b={\rm id}_{M_n(\mathbb R)}$.

Comment: Yes, it is the identity matrix. @ThomasShelby

Comment: I reread now ypur first comment and I got stuck at how you defined there $\phi_a$. Xould ypu explain it further to me? @saltandpepper

Comment: What I said was there is an isomorphism between the ring of endomorphisms and the ring of matricies. To say it another way, $End_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ contains all the linear maps. A matrix is just a linear map. So there is an endomorphism that is associated with a and another endomorphism associated with  b. The same goes for the identity matrix. Then you can use part 3 to finish to problem.

Comment: Ok! So we need to show statement 3 first. There are two hints: The first one is $\phi \text{ is injective } \iff \ker \phi =\{0\}$ and the second one is $n=\text{rank}\phi+\text{def} \phi$. From the statement 2 we get that $\phi$ is surjective. So we have to show that $\ker \phi =\{0\}$ so that $\phi$ is invertible, or not? Respectively, from statement 2 we get that $\psi$ is injective and using that $n=\text{rank}\psi+\text{def} \psi$ we can show that $\psi$ is surjective, and so it is invertible, right? Could you give me a hint how we can show these two things? @saltandpepper

Comment: Ok! So we need to show statement 3 first. There are two hints: The first one is $\phi \text{ is injective } \iff \ker \phi =\{0\}$ and the second one is $n=\text{rank}\phi+\text{def} \phi$. From the statement 2 we get that $\phi$ is surjective. So we have to show that $\ker \phi =\{0\}$ so that $\phi$ is invertible, or not? Respectively, from statement 2 we get that $\psi$ is injective and using that $n=\text{rank}\psi+\text{def} \psi$ we can show that $\psi$ is surjective, and so it is invertible, right? Could you give me a hint how we can show these two things? @ThomasShelby